# How to find the include route to a specific header in eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, header, include

I have a cpp file, a.cpp, which includes

```
a.cpp
  b.hpp
    c.hpp
    d.hpp
      e.hpp
  f.hpp
```

If I am interested in finding at what point e.hpp is included, I would like to get the path to it, i.e. b.hpp->d.hpp->e.hpp

I can see all the tree that is included in the Include Browser View, but this View doesn't let me search the results and for lots of includes this get unmanageable quickly

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar with gcc:

`g++ -H  source.cpp`

From the gcc docs:

> ```
> -H
>  Print the name of each header file used, in addition to other normal activities. Each name is indented to show how deep in the  #include stack it is. Precompiled header files are also printed, even if they are found to be  nvalid; an invalid precompiled header file is  printed with ...x and a valid one with ...!.
> ```

the output will show you who includes whom:

`........ /usr/include/pthread.h
......... /usr/include/sched.h
.......... /usr/include/time.h
.......... /usr/include/bits/sched.h`

Comment: That could partially solve the problem but I was wondering a solution from within eclipse :/ thanks anyways!

Comment: I don't know any from within eclipse, sorry!